# Screen resolution fell back to 1920x1080

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have a windows 7 guest system that was running on screen resolution 3840x2160 without any problem (host is windows 10 with a high resolution screen).

Yesterday I made a remote connection to the guest with a system that had a max screen resolution of 1920x1080. (The connection link was [remote] -> (remote desktop) -> [host] -> [guest]

Auto resizing was still using the host screen resolution of 3840x2160. Changing the screen resolution in the host to 1920x1080 was the only way to get a workable screen layout.

When I started to work on the guest with the host system the screen settings for the guest was still on 1920x1080. And no option to get any higher resolution!

Running a second guest with an identical setup gives me display options up to 3840x2160 in total five settings with resolutions bigger than 1920x1080 (but no choice for 1920x1080.)

I am running version 5.1.30 4118389 (Qt5.6.2) with the latest guest additions.
To be sure I reinstalled the guest additions.

Video memory for the guest is set to the max (of 128 Mb). I can't see any problems at the host side or guest configuration.

The video driver in the guest (VirtualBox Graphics Adaptor) is limiting my screen resolution settings so I think it is a problem related to the video driver.

Does anybody have a suggestion on how to solve this problem? I'm running out of options.

Comment: Have you rebooted the guest? sounds like it somehow got stuck. Rebooting should solve it. Alternatively, you can reinstall the VirtualBox guest addons.

Comment: @LPChip: did reinstall guest additions and rebooted (as said in my original message).

Comment: There's no mention of rebooting, so I wasn't sure. And installing the guest additions after a reboot is different than installing it first then reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some directions of handling this on a blog. (URL available on request.)

It came down to this:

```
You must run these commands after the virtual machine has been started.
You need to execute the following commands:
VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/MaxGuestResolution any
VBoxManage setextradata "Machine Name" "CustomVideoMode1" "Width x Height x Bpp"
VBoxManage controlvm "Machine Name" setvideomodehint Width Height Bpp
```

I did that with a setting of 3840x2160x32 and it fixed the problem.
Now the guest video driver gives me a long list of screen resolutions above 1920x1080, up to 6400x1200.

Looks like this fixed my problem for now.